# Twilio redirect function is not working on twilio studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-functions, twilio-studio

As question says twilio redirect function not working properly with flow (twilio studio).

When I select function on phone number for incoming messages it is working FINE.

[image]

---

But when I tried to redirect incoming msg using the function widget on studio, redirect not working properly and debug console says response body empty.

This is the redirect function

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
    const response = new Twilio.Response();
    response.appendHeader('Location', context.HTTP_REDIRECT_URL);
    callback(null, response);
};
```

Please advise what's happening here?

Do I need to transfer some key pairs using function widgets?

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:

Probably yes. But it is maybe better if you replace `context.HTTP_REDIRECT_URL` with the string literal `"http://example.com:myport"`

Longer answer:

Twilio does not know the value of `HTTP_REDIRECT_URL` from the ether.

The `context` parameter is propagated from the runtime environment variables, so you need to add that `HTTP_REDIRECT_URL` environment variable and a value to it.

Although I rather recommend you redirecting with `twiml.redirect(url)` rather than using the location header. That's more easy to debug.

(see the demo code for getting the twiml object)